# Unable to resolve service for type 'Schutters.Models.SchuttersContext' while attempting to activate 'Schutters.Controllers.ClubController'

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I just scaffolded my database classes into controllers and added the options to my view but when I try to click them on my navigation bar the action"Index" should be shown but I am receiving this error instead:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Schutters.Models.SchuttersContext'
> while attempting to activate 'Schutters.Controllers.ClubController'

My startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchuttersConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        
    }
```

}

The controller that gets called when I click "Clubs" on the navigation bar

```
public class ClubController : Controller
{
    private readonly SchuttersContext _context;

    public ClubController(SchuttersContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Club
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {...}
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you didn't register the `SchuttersContext`. Is it your database context class or what?

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had 2 connections 1 to a security database and 1 to my classes database. I had to add them both to the startup.cs class instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Fix I had 2 connections and had to put them both in the startup.cs class [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeOXT.png)